# jqGrid json format

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am currently reading data using ajax and using the data fetched to build a jqGrid using the code below:

```
$.getJSON(url, function (data) 
{
    createGrid(data);
});

function createGrid(data) 
{
    debugger;

    $("#gridCot").jqGrid(
    {
        datatype: "local",
        data: data.data,
        colNames: data.columnNames,
        colModel: data.columnModel,
        pager: "#pager",
        rownumbers: true,
        rowList: [10, 30, 50, 100, 200],
        rowNum: 50,
        height: 'auto',
        autowidth: true,
        height:600,
        shrinkToFit: false,
        loadonce: true,
        caption: "Test"
    });
}
```

This works great (except subsequent calls do not update the grid). **One question I had is how do I simply pass the 'data' the next time around to the grid so that it doesn't have to be created each time?** (currently the grid is not being created but also not updating with new data, prob due to the loadonce attribute)

I wanted to change the above to allow the grid itself to make the call, so I did the following:

```
$("#gridCot").jqGrid(
{
    url: serviceURL,
    datatype: "json",
    pager: "#pager",
    rownumbers: true,
    height: 'auto',
    width: '100%',
    loadonce: true,
    caption: "test",
    jsonReader: 
    {
        colNames: "columnNames",
        colModel: "columnModel",
        data: "data"
    }
});
```

This however renders a grid with no column or data. My question is, does the json format have to adhere to a specific format? I like the idea of the colModel because it means I don't have to post process my data much, which is quicker since I return a lot of columns. With the first method, my data is essentially serialized to an array of dictionaries (name, value). **Can this be achieved by the second method with out having to further 'massage' the data I am returning to the page?**

Thanks